# Persist unique value in react-select which is not present in options array

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to make `react-select` accept values which are not stored in the options array. I'm hoping to use this component to suggest values but also allow users to input their own value and persist it on blur.

In my situation the options represent suggestions which have been defined in the DB, on choosing an option it will auto-populate some other relevant fields.

However I also want to allow the user to define a unique value in the  and manually define the other values.

I don't want to feed the unique value in the options array because I do not want the user to see this as a selectable option.

Is this possible with `react-select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can totally control what's shown to the user as part of the selectable options, and also you have a dedicated class `Select-create-option-placeholder` attached to labels of new labels that need to be created (namely aren't part of the array of suggestions).